# How to run tests in Pytest in parallel inside the Docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, docker, pytest, xdist

I ran into a problem when running GUI tests in parallel inside a Docker container. I use a bunch: Selenium webdriver + Pytest + Xdist + Chrome.

I use following command to run the tests:

```
pytest -v -n=4 --headless=True --production=True --browser=chrome --dist=loadfile --junitxml=test.xml
```

But all the tests fail. If I do the same outside the docker container or use 1 thread - it's working fine.

So, how can I resolve this problem and execute tests in parallel inside the docker container? Thanks a lot)

I have this in logs:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable   (Session info: headless chrome=73.0.3683.86)   (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.20 (8e2b610813e167eee3619ac4ce6e42e3ec622017),platform=Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: Can you post the Dockerfile and docker command you use? Also when the tests are failing is there any error given?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post the dockerfile, the command that I use to run docker is 
    "docker run -it --rm <IMAGE> /bin/bash"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `boxed` processes + `tx` flag: (`--tx 3*popen//python=python3.6 --boxed`, so run your tests with the command below:

```
pytest -v --headless=True --production=True --browser=chrome --dist=loadfile --junitxml=test.xml --tx 3*popen//python=python3.6 --boxed
```

More information of how you can run your tests in parallel is available under [that SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56390281) .

**Good Luck !**